# Adding large number of rows using SQL

Tags: c#, sql, insert, oledb

My code works well when I'm adding less than 30 rows. But It can't handle more than that. How can I overcome this?

I get this error:`Unspecified error` when I'm trying to add less than 30, all the rows are added. and when I'm trying to add more than 30, it doesn't add nothing, and I get the error the number of the rows times.

Here is the code:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < st1.Length; i++)
                {
                    UpdateDataBase(st1[i]);
                }

private void UpdateDataBase(char letter)
    {
        letter = char.ToUpper(letter);
        int serialPro = 0;
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                  "Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        string sql = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo ";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
        try
        {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        //get the last!
        while (reader.Read())
            serialPro = reader.GetInt32(reader.Depth);


        sql = "INSERT INTO tblOrderAA (orderAASerialPro, orderAACodon1) "
           + " values (?, ?)";
        OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);

        command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAASerialPro", serialPro);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAACodon1", letter);
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("אירעה שגיאה ב: \n" + e.Message);
            this.Close();
        }
    }`
```

***EDIT:***
        private void UpdateDataBase(char letter)
        {
            letter = char.ToUpper(letter);
            int serialPro = 0;
           string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                  "Data Source=C:\Projects_2012\Project_Noam\Access\myProject.accdb";

```
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo ";
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    //get the last!
                    while (reader.Read())
                        serialPro = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }

                sql = "INSERT INTO tblOrderAA (orderAASerialPro, orderAACodon1) "
       + " values (?, ?)";
                using (OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAASerialPro", serialPro);
                    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAACodon1", letter);
                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("אירעה שגיאה ב: \n" + e.Message);
        }
    }
enter code here
```

Comment: It doesn't add nothing? So what _does_ it add?

Comment: nothing.but when the number of the rows is small, it adds all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but your OleDbConnection is never closed
Try the `using` statement which guarantees the closing and disposing of your connection

```
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo ";         
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);         
    try 
    {
     ......
    }
    catch(....)
}
```

also is not clear what your intent is in this line

```
serialPro = reader.GetInt32(reader.Depth);
```

**GetInt32** takes an int which is the ordinal number of the column required, while **reader.Depth** gets a value that indicates the depth of nesting for the current row.
I don't understand how the two values are related.

EDIT: In case you are looking for the max value of you serial number you could change the code in this way

```
string sql = "SELECT MAX(proInfoSerialNum) AS maxSN FROM tblProInfo ";                 
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))                 
{                     
    serialPro = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();                 
}
```

Comment: see what I wrote in @ThorstenDittmar answer

Comment: I fixed that error. SEE my EDIT How my code looks like now. I still get the error :`Unspecified error`

Comment: Could it be something with the `tblOrderAA` table. Do you have index or unique keys on your rows and trying to add duplicate records?

Comment: I don't think so.it is allowing to write the same number in `orderAASerialPro`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. The only thing that could be changed is removing of the reader for the serial number if it is correct to assume that you are looking for the highest value in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You might start by closing the database connections when you're done and you might get better results. Use the `using` statement to do so:

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    ...
}
```

The `using` statement makes sure that - for objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface - the `Dispose` method is called.

Also, the reader you're creating always stays open. So in the end, if rewritten, the method should look as follows:

```
private void UpdateDataBase(char letter)
{
    letter = char.ToUpper(letter);
    int serialPro = 0;
    string connectionString = "...";

    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT tblProInfo.proInfoSerialNum FROM tblProInfo ";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //get the last!
                while (reader.Read())
                    serialPro = reader.GetInt32(reader.Depth);
            }

            sql = "INSERT INTO ...";
            using (OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAASerialPro", serialPro);
                command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("orderAACodon1", letter);
                command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("אירעה שגיאה ב: \n" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

To speed things up: For every call you're selecting all serial numbers and then iterate over the reader to get the latest. Is there an index you can use to put this work into the database? Like: Order by some date or select `MAX(proInfoSerialNum)`? Otherwise your software will slow down *significantly* when there are more serial numbers in the database.

Comment: now I get this error:`Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0`

Comment: Sounds like the connection string is malformed. Of course I've shortened the text constants a little. Please put some effort into trying to understand the changes instead of simply copying and pasting it.

Comment: I fixed that error. SEE my EDIT How my code looks like now. I still get the error :Unspecified error

Comment: Up to which line are you able to execute the code? Did you debug? Does the Inner Exception show anything more?

Comment: "to debug" is the process of finding bugs, not just pressing `F5`. Did you set a breakpoint and single-step through the method to see where the error occurs? Is there any more information about the error itself?

Comment: i put many breakpoints, and the error is here:`                        while (reader.Read())
                            serialPro = reader.GetInt32(0);`

Comment: Now that's information! Could it be that the field in the database simply isn't an `Int32`? What if you rewrite this to: `while (reader.Read()) { object o = reader.GetValue(0); serialPro = Convert.ToInt32(o); }` This should give you the possibility to set a breakpoint to find out exactly what's returned by `reader.GetValue(0)`.

Comment: sorry, it falls much more earlier. in the `connection.Open();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11508/discussion-between-noam650-and-thorsten-dittmar)

Comment: of course that it is close!
So what do u think should i do?
there is a different aproach to INSERT multiple row?

Answer (score 0):

```
    void dataread()
    {
        query = "select * from nodes";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();

    }
```